# Outputting a loop of components and avoiding re-rendering the entire loop when only one component updates

Tags: reactjs

I am outputting a loop of the same component multiple times.

**Goal:** When the contents of a single instance of `SomeComponent` component updates, I'd like to avoid re-rendering the entire loop of components. If possible, I'd also like to avoid re-rendering the higher order component, `Panel`, that is surrounding the newly-updated `SomeComponent`.

**Problem**: Currently when I do this, all `Panel`s re-render, along with their child, `SomeComponent`.

*Function creating array of components:*

```
createPanels = () => {
  const numberOfPanels = 4
  const panelsArray = []
  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfPanels; index++) {
    panelsArray.push(
      <Panel>
        <SomeComponent theProp={willBeDynamic}/>
      </Panel>
    )
  }
  return panelsArray.map((panel) => panel)
}
```

*Render function:*

```
render(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>{this.createPanels()}</Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a feature I haven't learned yet that will allow me to re-render only one `Panel`'s `SomeComponent` or should I be structuring my code in another way? (Assume there is logic inside of `SomeComponent` that renders different content depending on the props it receives).

***Note**: The reason I'm using an array is that the order of items in that array will need to be reversed in some situations.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components can be wrapped in [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. It checks for prop changes:

This will re-render the updated item only:

```
const Panel = ({ children }) => {
  console.log("panel");
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const SomeComponent = ({ theProp }) => {
  console.log(theProp);
  return <div>Some Component Data {theProp}</div>;
};

const PanelComponent = React.memo(({ theProp }) => (
  <Panel>
    <SomeComponent theProp={theProp} />
  </Panel>
));

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { theProp: "theProp 1" },
    { theProp: "theProp 2" },
    { theProp: "theProp 3" }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData(prev => {
        prev[0].theProp = "theProp Updated";
        return [...prev]; // force update item 0
      });
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <PanelComponent theProp={item.theProp} key={`item_${index}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3bsp6p

Comment: Awesome, works great.  Thanks for the great explanation.  For anyone else reading, this is not the same as the useMemo hook ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `SomeComponent` a [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

Comment: Thanks, this does make sense but I only if your component is a class which you can extend PureComponent.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think this would work if you're trying to avoid re-renders for functional components.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It was not clear whether `SomeComponent` was a class component or not.